# 'IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT id, amount FROM report
```

I need `amount` to be `amount` if `report.type='P'` and `-amount` if `report.type='N'`. How do I add this to the above query?

Answer (score 1125, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       IF(type = 'P', amount, amount * -1) as amount
FROM report
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html.

Additionally, you could handle when the condition is null. In the case of a null amount:

```
SELECT id, 
       IF(type = 'P', IFNULL(amount,0), IFNULL(amount,0) * -1) as amount
FROM report
```

The part `IFNULL(amount,0)` means *when amount is not null return amount else return 0*.

Comment: I wonder if there is any advantage to using this IFNULL instead of COALESCE here?

Comment: From mysql source, I notice 2 definitions of coalesce, one with 2 arguments, and other with a list of arguments, but ifnull invokes the coalesce with 2 parameters `sql/item_cmpfunc.h 722:  Item_func_ifnull(Item *a, Item *b) :Item_func_coalesce(a,b) {}`

Comment: very useful: IFNULL(amount,0)

Comment: The answer is not correct if there are different report types than 'N' and 'P', see BadHorsie's comment in the better "case statement" solution.

Comment: @Trygve The question is for 2 conditions, and looking for an `IF` statement, what's wrong?

Comment: @Felipe, the answer is not necessarily 100% correct, there could be other report types than N and P. In your case, this could lead to an error, selecting -amount if report type (as an example) is 'E'. The question fails to mention if there are other report types though, so I remove my downvote. I just like to program defensively in these cases, so a heads up to other readers.

Answer (score 281):

Use a `case` statement:

```
select id,
    case report.type
        when 'P' then amount
        when 'N' then -amount
    end as amount
from
    `report`
```

Comment: @Evan: True.  I use them for clarity.  Not that it affects anything anyway.

Comment: I prefer ANSI standard syntax over custom syntax for a particular database.

Comment: This is the best solution because the accepted answer solution isn't necessarily appropriate if there are other values for report.type, or if a new report.type is introduced at a later date. It's saying `if report.type = 'P' use amount, otherwise use -amount for anything else`. it won't consider the type if it's not 'P'.

Answer (score 112):

```
SELECT CompanyName, 
    CASE WHEN Country IN ('USA', 'Canada') THEN 'North America'
         WHEN Country = 'Brazil' THEN 'South America'
         ELSE 'Europe' END AS Continent
FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY CompanyName;
```

Comment: Answer is unrelated to question!

Answer (score 48):

```
select 
  id,
  case 
    when report_type = 'P' 
    then amount 
    when report_type = 'N' 
    then -amount 
    else null 
  end
from table
```

Answer (score 15):

Most simplest way is to use a [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html). Yes Mysql allows you to do conditional logic. IF function takes 3 params CONDITION, TRUE OUTCOME, FALSE OUTCOME.

So Logic is

```
if report.type = 'p' 
    amount = amount 
else 
    amount = -1*amount
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
    id, IF(report.type = 'P', abs(amount), -1*abs(amount)) as amount
FROM  report
```

You may skip abs() if all no's are +ve only

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT id, amount
FROM report
WHERE type='P'

UNION

SELECT id, (amount * -1) AS amount
FROM report
WHERE type = 'N'

ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: As the result sets are mutually exclusive, I prefer UNION ALL here.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this also

```
 SELECT id , IF(type='p', IFNULL(amount,0), IFNULL(amount,0) * -1) as amount FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not fantastic, but I did this `IF()` nesting to normalize a few log messages that otherwise had unique values that made them not group:

```
SELECT 
    IF(process_error LIKE 'Already processed message id %', 'already processed',
      IF(process_error LIKE 'Cannot calculate size of %', 'sequence error', process_error)
    ) AS process_err,
    COUNT(id) AS process_count
FROM system_log
WHERE started >= '2023-06-01'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY process_count DESC
```

I wouldn't do this for more than a couple values, but for a throwaway query it's fine. It led to this output:

```
|process_err                                  |process_count|
|---------------------------------------------|-------------|
|already processed                            |617          |
|Failed to process message: uncaught error    |174          |
|sequence error                               |135          |
|Cannot read property 'FooBar' of undefined   |118          |
|Missing field BarBaz                         |8            |
|Ignoring: no matches found                   |1            |
```

Whereas without it, rows 1 and 3 would be spread out hundreds of rows.