# Using If else in SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement which will return 2 columns.

```
ID | IDParent
```

Then in my program I have to test `if IDParent is < 1 then use ID ELSE use IDParent`

Is there a way to use an If Else like condition in SQL to return only single value?

Comment: [Stack overflow link]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement Hope this helps

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63480/856172

Answer (score 114, accepted):

you can use `CASE`

```
SELECT   ...,
         CASE WHEN IDParent < 1 THEN ID ELSE IDPArent END AS ColumnName,
         ...
FROM     tableName
```

Answer (score 34):

Here, using [`CASE Statement`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx) and find result:

```
select (case when condition1 then result1
             when condition2 then result2
             else result3
             end) as columnname from tablenmae:
```

For example:

```
select (CASE WHEN IDParent< 1 then ID 
             else IDParent END) as columnname
from tablenmae
```

Answer (score 23):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IDParent < 1 
            THEN ID 
            ELSE IDParent 
       END AS colname 
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 7):

### Here are two ways "IF" Or "CASE".

```
SELECT IF(COLUMN_NAME = "VALUE", "VALUE_1", "VALUE_2") AS COLUMN_NAME 
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = "VALUE" THEN 'VALUE_1' ELSE 'VALUE_2' END) AS COLUMN_NAME 
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 4):

The query will be like follows

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN tuLieuSo is null or tuLieuSo=''
            THEN 'Chưa có đĩa' 
            ELSE 'Có đĩa' End) AS tuLieuSo,moTa
FROM [gPlan_datav3_SQHKTHN].[dbo].[gPlan_HoSo]
```

Answer (score 3):

sql server 2012

```
  with
  student as 
(select sid,year from (
values (101,5),(102,5),(103,4),(104,3),(105,2),(106,1),(107,4)
) as student(sid,year)
)
select iif(year=5,sid,year) as myCol,* from student


 myCol  sid year
101 101 5
102 102 5
4   103 4
3   104 3
2   105 2
1   106 1
4   107 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is some example using `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A > 1 THEN
            'Greater than 1'
    END  
FROM TRIANGLES
```

.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A > 1 THEN
            A
    END  
FROM TRIANGLES
```

.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A > 1 and B > 1 THEN
            'Greater than 1'
    END  
FROM TRIANGLES
```

.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A > 1 THEN
            'greater than 1'
         ELSE
            'less than 1'
    END  
FROM TRIANGLES
```

.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A > 1 THEN
            'greater than 1'
         ELSE CASE WHEN A >= 0 THEN
                      'greater than or equal 0'
                   ELSE
                      'less than 0'
              END        
    END  
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply `if` statement under `select` query as like I have described below

`if(some_condition,if_satisfied,not_satisfied)`

```
SELECT IF(IDParent < 1,ID,IDParent)  FROM yourTable ;
```

Comment: You propably meant [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a union construct. I'm not sure if CASE is a common SQL construct ...

```
SELECT ID FROM tabName WHERE IDParent<1 OR IDParent IS NULL
UNION 
SELECT IDParent FROM tabName WHERE IDParent>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CASE WHEN IDParent is < 1 then ID else IDParent END as colname 
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have a Query With This result :

```
SELECT Top 3
 id,
 Paytype
 FROM dbo.OrderExpresses
 WHERE CreateDate > '2018-04-08'
```

The Result is :

```
22082   1
22083   2
22084   1
```

I Want Change The Code To String In Query, So I Use This Code :

```
SELECT TOP 3
 id,
 CASE WHEN Paytype = 1 THEN N'Credit' ELSE N'Cash' END AS PayTypeString
 FROM dbo.OrderExpresses
 WHERE CreateDate > '2018-04-08'
```

And Result Is :)

```
22082   Credit
22083   Cash
22084   Credit
```