# Comparing two SQL Tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table being created daily that is downloaded from a suppliers website,containing product info, that is in `csv`. I have everything creating alright and all the tables are identical. The problem that I am needing solved is that I need to compare the tables between today and yesterday (table names are the dates in following format `mm-dd-yyyy`) I need to compare a few different columns for different things.

- I need to know all products that are in today's data that weren't in
  yesterdays (can be checked by supplier SKU)
- I need to know all product that were in yesterday's data that is no
  longer in today's
- I need to know when the price went up from yesterday's data
- I need to know when the price has gone down from yesterday's data
- I need to know when a sale has started based on yesterday's data as
  well as stopped

These need to show the following labels in the table that will show the changes

regular up
regular down
miscillanious change (description change or change to a fields that aren't a priority)
promo on (discount added from supplier)
promo off (discount taken off by supplier)
delete (no record of the product in new list {probably been deleted})
new item (new record of product in new list)
out of stock
I have been searching everywhere for the answer for these issues and have found stuff that kind of shows me how to do this using union and join but I don't fully understand how to use them based on this scenario.

I have tried different PHP solutions by going through each piece of data and searching for the sku in the new table and vice versa then checking for any changes if they exist in both tables but this is taking a really long time and I have over 200 000 products in these tables. I am hoping that I can do these in less queries and by letting the sql server do more work then the php script.

Thanks for all the help!

Yesterday's Table

```
 __________________________________________________________
| id | price | sale | description            | qty | sku   |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 12.50  |  0.00 | description product 1  | 12 | 12345 |
| 2 | 22.99  | 20.99 | describe the problem   | 1  | 54321 |
| 3 | 192.99 |  0.00 | description ftw        | 5  | 53421 |
| 4 | 543.52 |  0.00 | description            | 15 | 45121 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Today's Table

```
 __________________________________________________________
| id | price | sale | description            | qty | sku   |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 12.50  |  0.00 | description product 1  | 12 | 12345 |
| 2 | 22.99  |  0.00 | describe the problem   | 1  | 54321 |
| 3 | 192.99 | 50.00 | description ftw        | 5  | 53421 |
| 4 | 523.99 |  0.00 | description            | 15 | 45123 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

I need the new table to look like the following

```
 _____________________________________________________________
| id | sku    | label        | description            | price |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 54321  |  promo off   | describe the problem   | 22.99 |
| 2  | 53421  |  promo on    | description ftw        | 192.99|
| 3  | 45123  |  new item    | description            | 523.99|
| 4  | 45121  |  delete      | description            | 543.52|
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

The following is the code I have for the deleted and new items currently. I am using int for the label/status in the example below and just signifying the different numbers.

```
    $deleted = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test1`") or die(mysql_error());

    while($skus= mysql_fetch_array($deleted))
    {

        $query = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test2` WHERE SKU='".$skus['sku']."'"));

        if($query < 1)
        {

            $tata= mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gday` (Contract_Price, SKU, status) VALUES (".$skus['price'].", ".$skus['sku'].", 1)");
        }
    }


    $deleted = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test2`") or die(mysql_error());

while($skus= mysql_fetch_array($deleted))
{

    $query = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test1` WHERE SKU='".$skus['sku']."'"));

    if($query < 1)
    {

        $tata= mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gday` (Contract_Price, SKU, status) VALUES (".$skus['price'].", ".$skus['sku'].", 2)");
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The Following is the true table that all the data will be going into. I originally didn't want to muddy the water with the large table but by request I have included it.

```
ID
Status
DiscountDate
Price
Discount
DiscountEndDate
Desc1
Desc2
Desc3
Warranty
Qty1
Qty2
PricingUnit
PriceUpdate
Vendor
Category
UPC
Weight
WeightUnit
```

Comment: How would you display a status for a product for which price has been changed and sale started or ended?

Comment: My full table will be much larger then the test ones here. I have put the columns that I will be actually adding in the new table in an edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the size of your database I could propose you an SQL solution.

When you work with a lot of data, PHP can be slow for several reason.

You can try to do some functions.

You just have to store the status data in an other table. This is the documentation to write a trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Becareful if you have a lot of operation on your table I can suggest you to use PostgresSQL instead of mysql because I found it more simple to write function, trigger, ... using [PL/sql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql.html)

EDIT: Just have to write a simple function

I'm working on it at the moment. Think about using select case like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement)

**EDIT: Core function**

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE export()
BEGIN
        (SELECT today.id, today.sku, 
    CASE today.price
     WHEN today.price = yesterday.price THEN  'nothing'
     WHEN today.price < yesterday.price THEN 'promo on'
     ELSE 'promo off' END AS label
    FROM today, yesterday WHERE yesterday.sku = today.sku)
    UNION
    (
    SELECT today.id, today.sku, 
    'new item' AS label
     FROM today LEFT JOIN yesterday ON yesterday.sku = today.sku WHERE yesterday.sku IS NULL)
    UNION
    (
    SELECT yesterday.id, yesterday.sku,  
    'delete' AS label
     FROM yesterday LEFT JOIN today ON today.sku = yesterday.sku WHERE today.sku IS NULL
    );
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

To call just do:

```
CALL export();
```

Here is an example of possible core functions. Be careful in this case id could be the same. In the function you'll have to add a personal one in the first column.

If you need performance to display it faster in PHP, think about [APC cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Comment: I have just looked into the triggers and they seem like a great idea, the only thing is that it appears that you can only use one. I don't know if I would be able to get all the status' I need using triggers. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes you are just able to create one per event. But you can adapt the treatment while triggering. For exemple if OLD.price has change, you update what you need, if the product has been delete you launch an other one trigger, ... Does it help? If you need I can edit the answer.

Comment: I have been looking at triggers in more detail and if you could please do edit your answer a bit. The thing is is that I need to check so many things to the old table that I don't know how to go about writing all of those things into one trigger.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I work on it on my machine and I'll edit this answer. It could take several time because I'm better creating function using PG than mysql but I'll try to help you