# if/Else/Else if/ statement in sql

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I have a query that goes something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(`table`.points) AS total_points FROM table
```

This will return something like this

```
|    **points**   |
        324
```

Now I want to add another result next to it depending on the total points that the user has and display it. Below is the sample that I am trying to achieve

```
if (total_points >= 50 && < 100) {
  //display another column next to the points
  another_rows AS total_points + 50  
} else if (total_points >= 100 && < 200) {
  another_rows AS total_points + 100  
} else if (total_points >= 200 && < 300) {
  another_rows AS total_points + 200  
} else if (total_points >= 300 || 300) {
  another_rows AS total_points + 300  
} else {
  another_rows AS total_points
}
```

Desire results:

```
|    **points**   |     **another_row**   |
        324                   824
```

Comment: To use an IF, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Why do you prefer to do this in SQL vs PHP?

Comment: I am doing a ranking system, that's why I prefer doing this in sql

Comment: On a different note, the condition seems wrong. You're not likely to reach the `else` block if `total_points == 324`.

Comment: @user3135626 Can you give some demo DB data?

Comment: so if user has less than 50 points he has 500+ points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL has a construct called `CASE` for these usecases exactly:

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS total_points,
       SUM(points) +
       CASE 
         WHEN SUM(points) BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 50
         WHEN SUM(points) BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN 100
         WHEN SUM(points) BETWEEN 200 AND 300 THEN 200
         WHEN SUM(points) BETWEEN 300 AND 400 THEN 300
         ELSE 500
       END AS another_row
FROM  `table`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [CASE WHEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) for this:

```
select SUM(`table`.points) AS total_points,
  CASE SUM(`table`.points) AS total_points 
  WHEN total_points >= 50 AND total_points < 100 THEN
    total_points + 50 AS another_row
  WHEN total_points >= 100 AND total_points < 200 THEN
    total_points + 100 AS AS another_row
  WHEN total_points >= 200 AND total_points < 300 THEN
    total_points + 200 AS AS another_row
  WHEN total_points >= 300 AND total_points < 400 THEN
    total_points + 300 AS AS another_row
  ELSE
    total_points + 500 AS AS another_row
  END CASE
FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

```
SELECT SUM(`table`.points) AS total_points ,Case when (total_points>= 50 &&< 100)
  then
  another_rows AS total_points + 50  
case
 when (total_points >= 100 && total_points< 200) then
   total_points + 100 
case when (total_points >= 200 && total_points< 300)then
   total_points + 200  
case when (total_points >= 300 && total_points< 400)then
  total_points + 300  
else
  total_points + 500 
end as another_rows 

From table
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for right?

```
SELECT 
    total_points,
    CASE    
        WHEN  
            total_points > 100 
        AND
            total_points < 200
        THEN (total_points + 50)

        WHEN  
            total_points > 200 
        AND
            total_points < 300
        THEN (total_points + 100)
    END AS another_row
FROM
    # from clause
WHERE
    # where clause
```