# Price Comparision in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case, where-clause

I have a price:

```
$price = 100;
```

I have 2 Database fields

```
1) priceType
2) price
```

Now the cases are:

```
if priceType =1

CASE 1: price <= $price // Do this comparison in WHere Clause

if priceType =2

CASE 2: price* (800000 / 1000) <= '$price' // Do this comparison in WHere Clause
```

Only one operation should be performed at a time, depends on priceType.

If priceType = 1 than the $price should be compared in first case way.

If priceType = 2 than the $price should be compared in second case way.

I want to perform this in Where Clause.

What should the query look like ?

Comment: If you use MySQL take a look at the IF statement or look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement

Comment: Post updated please check

Comment: You have 2 answers, what's wrong with either?

Comment: Its not generating the right output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE (CASE priceType WHEN 1 THEN price WHEN 2 THEN price * (800000 / 1000) END) <= $price
```

Comment: Can you explain this query ?

Comment: @CodeHunter My query is doing same what you had asked for

Answer (score 0):

or with `IF`:

```
SELECT
    IF (priceType = 1, price,
        IF (priceType = 2, price * (800000 / 1000),
            'unknown priceType'
        )
    ) AS price
FROM priceTable
```

Update:

I maybe missunderstood...

```
SELECT price
FROM priceTable
WHERE (priceType = 1 AND price <= " . $price . ")
OR    (priceType = 2 AND (price* (800000 / 1000)) <= " . $price . ")
```