# How to make a PHP if statment dependent on SQL query results

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, echo

I am trying to echo out the user level depending on whether the user level is either 1 or 5 based on SQL data results. Here:

```
<?php while ($rrows = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results)) {?>
      <tr> 
        <td><input name="u[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>"     id="u[]"></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrows['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrows['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrows['user_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrows['user_email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php ?></td>
```

So I need a sort of `if` statement to select the user level from `$rrows['id']` then if that selected data is 1 echo out "Network" and if it is "5" echo out "Administrator". How can this be done?

Comment: where do you want to display that?

Comment: Just because the data's coming from mysql doesn' tmean you can't use a normal `if($row['id'] == 'something') { ...}` type construct...

Comment: First, you did all this but can't do an `if` statement?  And second, probly easier to use a `switch-case`.  What's the `<td><?php ?></td>` for?  No need for that empty PHP snippet

Comment: echo ($rrows['id']==1)?"Network":"Administrator";

Comment: @yani want it to be displayed in the empty <td><?php ?></td> part.

Comment: Take a look at the full answer I added :)

Comment: @Sadikhasan    That would work but it is not the ID field, the ID field is to make sure the correct user's data is found, then it would have to select the right coloum which is 'user_level'

Comment: @user3234195 The title says 'solved' did you find the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need something like that:

```
$user_levels = array('Network','role2','role3','role4','Administrator');

<?php while ($rrows = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results)) {?>
      <tr> 
        <td><input name="u[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>"     id="u[]"></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrows['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrows['date']; ?></td>           
        <td><?php echo $users_levels[(int)$rrows['id']-1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrows['user_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrows['user_email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php ?></td>
```

The reason I am using -1 in the array is because the array is 0 based and your roles start with 1.
If you need to use the 'user_level' simply replace the row with

```
<td><?php echo $users_levels[(int)$rrows['user_level']-1]; ?></td>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just tired this one, didn't show anything up. Thank you for the suggestion though!:)

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work, did you replace 'id' with 'user_level'?

Comment: @Yani          Nope, i just tried it again and it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in {path}

Comment: seems like you have an error before the code you posted...maybe forgot to put ';', or close an if or a loop...

Comment: Yeah i found the error, but still nothing is being displayed; brings up no errors just nothing being outputted.

Comment: @user3234195 I'm a programmer not a psychic...can't debug something I can't see. Are all your other table rows being generated ok? Is your query working? Can't read your mind sorry...my answer should solve the specific problem you posted...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it with a if statement. I'd do it like that:

```
$levels = array(1 => "Network", 5 => "Administrator");
echo $levels[$rrows['user_level']];
```

That way, if you want to add other levels, you just add a value to the array and that's it.

Comment: Just tried this, didn't show anything up either! Hmm thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Just as my colleague Yani said, there's no reason this shouldn't work. What is inside $$rows['id']? Do you have another field in your database, like user_level?

Comment: $rrows['id' is the unique ID for each user, then within that database(table) there is fields including name etc, then user_level which is a number, then that number i want changing to a word depending on the number queried.

Comment: OK. Can you confirm user_level is either 1 or 5 ? If so, you should just echo $levels[$rrows['user_level']] and that would do it.

Comment: @StephaneMombuleu - You solved it! That last comment fixed it, now works as I'd like it. Thank you!:)

Comment: Perfect! Make sure you understand how this works. There's no point in copy/pasting without understanding, keep that in mind. In the long run I promise it will be valuable :)

Comment: Cool! Don't hesitate to upvote and validate my comment then :D Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how you got that far without an if statement but anyway, you also could do this right in you sql query. I always try to outsource as much logic to mysql as possible for a balanced load distribution.

```
SELECT level, IF(level = 1, 'Network', 'Administrator') as level FROM table
```

I think you can nest if statements to have more options.

Adapted from this answer: ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement)