# SQL - Matching resulting columns

Tags: mysql, sql

quick question:

trying to come up with a column that displays the rows that are different of two columns:

I am looking for table 3 as the following:

The first 2 columns consist of SUM functions. I am looking to determine which rows are different (dont match) and display the value thats in column 2 in column 3. Any ideas?

For example

`Column 1`    `Column 2`  `Column 3`

```
1            1         
2            3        3
4            4
```

Comment: You can use `CASE` for this like `CASE WHEN col1 = col2 THEN '' ELSE col2 END as col3`.

Comment: I tried to use CASE. the problem is that those values are already cases, as follows:
 SUM(CASE WHEN super.Guid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) and the other column is just a count. So how can I have a CASE that joins both?

Comment: Another option would be to use the other query as a sub query and then use case to calculate the third column. like `SELECT *, (our case) FROM (your query) as x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have that one as a subquery. This would be the "idea"

```
SELECT T.Column1, T.Column2, CASE WHEN T.Column1 == T.Column2 THEN NULL ELSE Column2 end 
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN super.Guid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column1, 
               COUNT(...) as Column2
    FROM... ) T
```

Comment: What would I have for "Column1" and "Column2"?

Comment: Column1 and Column2 would be the name you want to add for your columns (result of the case you were talking about). In the second SELECT, I named the first SUM(CASE..) as Column1 and the second as Column2

Comment: so for your current code: SUM(CASE WHEN super.Guid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Column1, COUNT(adver.Name) As Column2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql's IF()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement) for this:  If they are not equal, select COlumn2, else NULL:

```
SELECT IF(Column1 <> Column2, Column2, NULL) AS Column3
```

Comment: Right, how would my syntax look as far as "Column1" and "Column2". The fields I am using are SUM(CASE WHEN super.Guid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) and the other column is COUNT(adver.Name)