# Mysql IF in statement

Tags: mysql

In my users table I have a field `hours`, and when I'm selecting all my users I need to also get a variable `fullTime` which will be based on if `hours` equals `7.4`. Is this something I can do in a query rather than having to loop through all the users? I have 600+ rows and I'm trying to do this the most efficient way as this happens on every page load. I was thinking something like `SELECT *, fullTime as (hours EQUALS 7.4) FROM users`

EDIT: Working SQL `SELECT * , IF(hours_per_day = 7.5, 1, 0) AS fullTime FROM users`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL 'IF' in 'SELECT' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement)

Comment: what is your table columns and data?

Comment: The simplest way is `(hours >= 7.4) as FullTime`.  You don't need either `if` or `case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return a column with `fulltime` = 1 if hours = 7.4 and `fulltime` = 0 otherwise.

```
SELECT *, IF(hours = 7.4, 1, 0) AS fulltime FROM users
```

Note that this may fail if hours is a float column due to inaccuracies in floating point numbers.

Comment: Works a treat :) thanks, I'll accept when SO lets me :P.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT * , if(hours >= 7.4 ,col_time, hours) as fullTime  FROM users
```

explanation  :

if hours >=7.4 (not only exactly hours=7.4 but also greater.) you will get your column where you stored the full date with time or whole time. you can even change it by DATE_FORMAT. otherwise you will get the hours lets say 5 ,or something.

Comment: Whilst I can see the benefit of `>=` this project is a little weird because people on 7.5+ hours are classes by HR as part time, it's only 7.4 exactly who are full time.