# Subquery inside IF() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an error in my SQL code:

```
SELECT IF(1>2,select * from table2,select * from table1)
```

this make following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from table2,select * from table1)' at line 1
```

i dont know why this;
i have multiple condition based query but i cant run simple if statement please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL 'IF' in 'SELECT' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement)

Comment: That's not a PhpMyAdmin problem at all. Invalid SQL code will simply not run anywhere. I've edited the question to remove the references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:MAKE SURE YOU ARE USING THE RIGHT DATABASE WHICH INCLUDES THESE TWO TABLES(table1, table2)

```
  DELIMITER |
   CREATE FUNCTION dataselect()
   BEGIN

    CASE 1>2 
      WHEN 1 THEN select * from table2;
      WHEN 0 THEN select * from table1;
    END CASE;
   END;

   |
```

and then call it :

```
  CALL dataselect();
```

Comment: now i just try your code its make the following error ` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN  `

Comment: I HAVE MADE SOME CHANGES, PLEASE TRY THIS