# Concenate String with Dynamic Value

Tags: php, sql, string-concatenation, concatenation

I am trying to concenate a string with values from a database and change the variable $protocol according to the value of 'Operating_System'

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CONCAT('<OS=\"',Operating_System,'\" Protocol=\"RDP\"/>') as nodestring FROM `serverlist`;");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['nodestring'];
}
```

So for example: if value of 'Operating_System' !== 'Windows' then change $protocol to "SSH".
Any help on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered to use mysql IF for that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement

Comment: I was thinking about something like this but I didn't get the syntax right for my example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
            "SELECT CONCAT(
                 '<OS=\"', Operating_System, '\" Protocol=\"', 
                        IF (Operating_System != 'Windows', 'SSH', 'RDP')
                  , '\"/>') as nodestring FROM `serverlist`;");
```

However this is NOT SUGGESTED to do it, you can simply achieve that with PHP after your query. It is not a good practice to have HTML in your mysql at all. It will just make things more complicated without any particular reason. So I am suggesting something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
               "SELECT Operating_System as operating_system FROM `serverlist`;");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $protocol =  $row['operating_system'] != 'Windows' ? 'SSH' : 'RDP';
    echo '<OS="' . $row['operating_system'] . '" Protocol="' . $protocol . '"/>';
}
```

The second solution is much more maintainable than the first one and the code is more readable.