# mysql assertion in sql script

Tags: mysql, sql-scripts

I have a script that needs to be executed only when some condition is met. For example condition is defined in the following way:

```
select 1 from table_name where id = 123
```

if query returns row condition is met, otherwise condition is not met and script should not execute.

How can I implement this conditional logic in an sql script which is then executed with `mysql` client:

```
mysql < script.sql
```

It seems that conditionals are not supported in sql scripts, but probably there are some workarounds (without creating and running procedure).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL 'IF' in 'SELECT' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement)

Comment: @lolka_bolka, I do not need conditions in select statement, I need condition in sql script

Comment: @lolka_bolka, ok, how can I stop sql script execution using conditionals in sql statement?