# Mysql calculation and conditional logic as virtual field

Tags: mysql

I have a table called BooksUser. I has two `date` fields `returned_on_date` and `return_by_date`. Can i do the below calculations in mysql as a virtual field, `status`.

```
if(empty(BooksUser['returned_on_date'])){
    if(date('Y-m-d') > BooksUser['return_by_date']){
        BooksUser['status'] = 1;
    } else {
        BooksUser['status'] =  2;
    }
} else {
    if(BooksUser['returned_on_date'] > BooksUser['return_by_date']) {
        BooksUser['status'] = 3;
    } else {
        BooksUser['status'] = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a IF statement.  Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement

Comment: Well, there is an `IF` statement in SQL and there are string and date functions. I suggest you start reading the documentation for those. you should only ask such a question here _after_ you tried yourself. And then you should ask with a specific issue you have within your attempt. Here you are basically asking: could someone please do my work for me?

Comment: @arkascha sure thanks for letting me know about if statement. I will delet this question and ask back if needed

Comment: @Tommo1977 thanks.  It was so simple that now i feel why i wasted so may day in it. But again i didn't know mysql had IF. so thanks. Suggest any site/book to learn more about mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    IF(isnull(returned_on_date), 
        IF(CURDATE() < return_by_date, 1, 2), 
        IF(returned_on_date > return_by_date, 3, 4)
    ) as status 
from books_users
```

Basically this is what is happening. As suggested by comments `IF` is was what i had to use and in my case trick was to use nested IF's.

IF function takes 3 params CONDITION, TRUE OUTCOME, FALSE OUTCOME.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: You can you please explain your answer ?