# Select attributes based on a specific attribute

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with selecting data from rows based on specific attribute value. Let's say I have a value for attribute `id` and a row with multiple attributes including `con_post_id`, which can be `NULL` or another row's `id` value (like a link). Would it be possible if `con_post_id` was not `NULL`, to select some attributes from the current row and others in the row with `id=con_post_id`? But if `con_post_id` was `NULL` it would select all attributes of row with the starting value `id`?

```
id  user_id store_id status_id con_post_id con_like_id thought   time                product_flag_id removed views locked type
494      63 NULL             0        NULL        NULL somevalue 2015-03-06 17:14:16             397       0     0      0 user
508      63 NULL             4         494          56           2015-03-06 17:58:50            NULL       0     0      0 user
```

The query for row with `id=494` should return all its values of attributes, but a query for row with `id=508` should return `user_id, status_id` from the current row and `thought, product_flag_id, removed, views, locked and type` from the row with `id=494`.

I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Take a look at IF syntax.  Here's one of probably many questions that have been answered showing ways to do what you're looking to do using IF.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values

Comment: So this is a self-referencing table?

Comment: @MikeBrant yes you could call it that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could self-join the table using a left join, then use some conditionals to determine which values to show depending on whether this is a "child" or "parent" record that was requested.

```
SELECT
  child.user_id AS user_id,
  child.status_id AS status_id,
  IF(
    /*
      if this value is NULL there is no "parent" record
      so get the value from child record
      similar to all values with "IF" condition
    */
    child.con_post_id IS NULL, 
    child.thought,
    parent.thought
  ) AS thought,
  IF(
    child.con_post_id IS NULL, 
    child.product_flag_id,
    parent.product_flag_id
  ) AS product_flag_id,
  IF(
    child.con_post_id IS NULL, 
    child.removed,
    parent.removed
  ) AS removed,
  IF(
    child.con_post_id IS NULL, 
    child.views,
    parent.views
  ) AS views,
  IF(
    child.con_post_id IS NULL, 
    child.locked,
    parent.locked
  ) AS locked,
  IF(
    child.con_post_id IS NULL, 
    child.type,
    parent.type
  ) AS type
FROM table AS child
LEFT JOIN table AS parent
  ON child.con_post_id = parent.id
WHERE child.id = ?
```

Comment: Thank you, you've set me on the right path :) Also, is this the only way?

Comment: @UrosHercog It is probably the most straightforward way given your table schema., and assuming you want to get all data with a single query. It is notoriously clumsy dealing with hierarchical data structures in relational databases.