# How to insert an alternative value from an old table into a new table IF NULL.

Tags: sql, insert-update, ifnull

I have this old_table.

```
ID:    First_name:    Last_name:    Age:
1      Christian      Johnson       25
2      John           Christiansen  21
3      <NULL>         Peterson      23
```

and this new_table I just created, by this piece of code:

`CREATE TABLE new_table (ID integer, name text, age text);`

`INSERT INTO new_table (ID, name, age) SELECT ID, First_name, age FROM old_table;`

Which returned:

```
ID    Name:        Age:
1     Christian    25
2     John         21
3     <NULL>       23
```

But I would love my code to insert the lastname, if it encounters a NULL-value. So in pseudo-code;

`(...) SELECT ID, First_name IF NULL last_name, age FROM old_table;`

The IF NULL last_name doesn't work.

Comment: someone already asked the similar problem, possibly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values) may help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `COALESCE()`, which returns the first not-null values it encounters:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (ID, name, age) 
    SELECT ID, COALESCE(First_name, Last_name), age FROM old_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:
`INSERT INTO new_table (ID, name, age) SELECT ID, COALESCE(First_name,Last_name), age FROM old_table;`

`COALESCE` will go through the listed values and choose the first one that isn't `NULL`  It's more portable code than `ISNULL` or `IVNL`, etc.

Comment: What SQL language doesn't support `ISNULL`? I'm just curious since I only being using MS SQL.

Comment: Oracle, just to name a big one.  There are several others.