# How to select column conditionally according to another one in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (users) which has columns as the following:

```
userid  name  email  system_photo  personal_photo  photo_select
```

`photo_select` can have two values (1 or 0). I want to select `system_photo` or `personal_photo` according to `photo_select` value. If `photo_select` is `1` then `personal_photo` should be selected, else if `photo_select` is `0` then `system_photo` should be selected.

`system_photo` value comes from another service. If the user does not like that photo, s/he can upload a new one. On another day, s/he will be able to switch between the two photos.

I have first selected all three columns, and in the view section of my code, I have written

```
if($user->photo_select === '0')
    echo $user->system_photo;
else if($user->photo_select === '1')
    echo $user->personal_photo;
```

but then I thought that this is a costly way. And I have decided to select only one photo column (`system_photo` or `personal_photo`) in the model section. What should be my MySQL `SELECT` statement to achieve this?

Comment: `0 !== '0'` && `1 !== '1'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
select *, if(photo_select = 0, system_photo,personal_photo) as photo
from users
```

you can use if statements in your query based if its true or false you will select 1 column or the other.... then finally you cast it as whatever you want to call it maybe..... photo

Comment: why use * if only one column needs to be selected ?

Comment: All the answers work. Because this answer is the first, it deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT IF(photo_select = 1, personal_photo, system_photo) as photo from users
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN photo_select=1 then personal_photo
    ELSE system_photo
END AS display_photo from users 
where userid=1
```