# How can i use mysql alias column in if statement

Tags: php, mysql, alias

Unknown column 'CURRENT_STOCK_LEVEL' in 'field list'

```
$queryString = 'SELECT A.ITEM_CODE, A.BEGINNING_BALANCE AS BEGINNING_BALANCE, B.DELIVERY AS DELIVERY, C.ISSUANCE AS ISSUANCE, 
(IFNULL(BEGINNING_BALANCE, 0) + IFNULL(DELIVERY, 0)) - IFNULL(ISSUANCE, 0) AS CURRENT_STOCK_LEVEL , A.REORDERPNT AS REORDERPNT,

IF( CURRENT_STOCK_LEVEL <= REORDERPNT, "LOW", "HIGH") AS STATUS

FROM MM_NEW_ROP_ITEMS AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ITEM_CODE, SUM(QUANTITY) AS ISSUANCE FROM MM_NEW_ROP_ISSUANCES GROUP BY ITEM_CODE) AS C ON A.ITEM_CODE = C.ITEM_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ITEM_CODE, SUM(QUANTITY) AS DELIVERY FROM MM_NEW_ROP_DELIVERIES GROUP BY ITEM_CODE) AS B ON A.ITEM_CODE = B.ITEM_CODE
ORDER BY A.ITEM_CODE'; 

$query = mysql_query($queryString) or die(mysql_error());

//makes a loop and creates an array with query fields

$items = array();
while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $items[] = $item;
}

//encodes for JSON format
echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => mysql_errno() == 0,
    "items" => $items
));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Comment: You can't use alias in if statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT A.ITEM_CODE, A.BEGINNING_BALANCE, B.DELIVERY AS DELIVERY, C.ISSUANCE, 
       (IFNULL(BEGINNING_BALANCE, 0) + IFNULL(DELIVERY, 0)) - IFNULL(ISSUANCE, 0) AS CURRENT_STOCK_LEVEL ,
       A.REORDERPNT AS REORDERPNT,
       IF(CURRENT_STOCK_LEVEL <= REORDERPNT, 'LOW', 'HIGH') AS STATUS
```

As the error suggests, you cannot re-use a column alias in the same `SELECT` statement where it is defined.  This applies not only to the `SELECT`, but also to other components of the query such as `WHERE`.

So, repeat the logic, and I prefer `COALESCE()` and `CASE` (this is the ANSI standard function):

```
SELECT A.ITEM_CODE, A.BEGINNING_BALANCE, B.DELIVERY AS DELIVERY, C.ISSUANCE, 
       (COALESCE(BEGINNING_BALANCE, 0) + COALESCE(DELIVERY, 0)) - COALESCE(ISSUANCE, 0)) AS CURRENT_STOCK_LEVEL ,
       A.REORDERPNT AS REORDERPNT,
       (CASE WHEN COALESCE(BEGINNING_BALANCE, 0) + COALESCE(DELIVERY, 0)) - 
                  COALESCE(ISSUANCE, 0) <= REORDERPNT
             THEN 'LOW' ELSE 'HIGH'
        END) AS STATUS
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon LinOff! really save my time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL session variables which do your job without repeating the logic.

Here is the way to do that in query:

```
SELECT A.ITEM_CODE, A.BEGINNING_BALANCE AS BEGINNING_BALANCE, B.DELIVERY AS DELIVERY, C.ISSUANCE AS ISSUANCE, 
    @temp_stock_level:=0, @temp_stock_level:=(IFNULL(BEGINNING_BALANCE, 0) + IFNULL(DELIVERY, 0)) - IFNULL(ISSUANCE, 0) AS CURRENT_STOCK_LEVEL , 
    A.REORDERPNT AS REORDERPNT,IF( @temp_stock_level <= REORDERPNT, "LOW", "HIGH") AS STATUS
    FROM MM_NEW_ROP_ITEMS AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ITEM_CODE, SUM(QUANTITY) AS ISSUANCE FROM MM_NEW_ROP_ISSUANCES GROUP BY ITEM_CODE) AS C ON A.ITEM_CODE = C.ITEM_CODE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ITEM_CODE, SUM(QUANTITY) AS DELIVERY FROM MM_NEW_ROP_DELIVERIES GROUP BY ITEM_CODE) AS B ON A.ITEM_CODE = B.ITEM_CODE
    ORDER BY A.ITEM_CODE;
```

In this query I have used @temp_stock_level variable to store value `CURRENT_STOCK_LEVEL`