# Mysql column string based on int

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to output a string depending on the value of int column. The query is below and language_id is an int column.

```
select email, language_id from tgf_mobileuser where email is not null;
```

What I want to do is get 'English' if language_id is 0, Japanese if language_id is 1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding this into the query, it would be better to have a language table that contains the language name for each ID. Then you can join with the table.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the useful tip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement to achieve what you want:

```
select email, 
    CASE language_id WHEN 0 THEN 'English'
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'Japanese'
                     ELSE 'Unknown'
    END as Language
from tgf_mobileuser 
where email is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following something similar to this other post using an if clause in the select statement.
['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)