# Select statement for hours start and end time

Tags: mysql, select, time

I have a table which have integer columns startTime, and endTime (ex. 60 means 1:00 am, 120 mean 2:00 am, 1320 mean 10:00 PM.....etc)

sometimes endTime value might be less than startTime (starts at 10PM and ends at 2AM, then startTime will be 1320 and endTime will be 60)

Now If user entered 11PM to find if 11PM (1380) is between 10PM (1320) and 2AM (120).... what is the SQL statement that I need to find this.

I am using:
select * from dayTimes where 1380 BETWEEN startTime and endTime.

I need just a select statement without complex query

Comment: well if you are just trying to check if 1380 is between startTime and endTime, that script of yours should work, it does make sense

Comment: @VJPPaz But in my case, it's checking if 1380 BETWEEN 1320 and 120

Comment: PLSQL in MySQL? Now the question is: MySQL or Oracle is your RDBMS?

Comment: My Mistake, it's MySQL DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If start time and end time doesn't exceeds 24 hrs duration, following code will work:

```
select * from dayTimes where 540 BETWEEN startTime and 
if(endTime-startTime>=0,endTime,1440+endTime)
OR
540+1440 BETWEEN startTime and 
if(endTime-startTime>=0,endTime,1440+endTime)
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I have the following values, 1080 as startTime, 660 as endTime, and user entered 540..... your solution do not work with this scenario...right

Comment: @Dev : Yes. you are right. I missed that point. I have corrected the query by adding another condition using `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Case`  statement for this type of sql statement in MySQL.

For your problem, something like this should work.

```
Select *,
    Case When startTime>endTime THEN 1380 BETWEEN endtime and endTime+startTime
         When endTime>startTime THEN 1380 BETWEEN startTime and endTime
from dayTimes
```

Besides, you may want to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0):

you can break this problem into two parts and then check:

First part is check if given time is between 'startTime' and 1439(i.e 11:59 PM) 
Second Part(Comes into picture if given time is between 00:00 and endTime)

```
select * from dayTimes where 1300 between startTime and 1439 or 1300 between 0000 and endTime;
```