# Getting error by using IF with JOIN in SELECT mysql

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement, select, join

I am new to IF statement in mysql query. I follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values) to write my own query.

Basically I am trying to select data if an attribute in `Base table "Peripheral"` **then** *join Base table with Peripheral* table, **Else** *join Base table with other table*.

Following query which I have tried to build:

```
SELECT * FROM CC_FIRMWARE 

INNER JOIN 

IF(CC_FIRMWARE.Device_Class = "Peripheral", 
    RC_Peripheral_Type ON RC_Peripheral_Type.Id = CC_FIRMWARE.Device_Type_Id, 
    RC_Box_Type ON RC_Box_Type.Id = CC_FIRMWARE.Device_Type_Id)

WHERE CC_FIRMWAER.Id = 4;
```

I am getting syntax error. `unexpected 'IF' (if)`

Comment: IF is for select filed  not for table

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want something like this:

```
SELECT         *
FROM           CC_FIRMWARE
LEFT JOIN      RC_Peripheral_Type 
          ON   RC_Peripheral_Type.Id = CC_FIRMWARE.Device_Type_Id
          AND  CC_FIRMWARE.Device_Class = "Peripheral"
LEFT JOIN      RC_Box_Type 
          ON   RC_Box_Type.Id = CC_FIRMWARE.Device_Type_Id
          AND  CC_FIRMWARE.Device_Class <> "Peripheral"
WHERE          CC_FIRMWARE.Id = 4
```

This is pretty basic stuff, I think you should read up on the basics of SQL and/or set based operations. If you think about the logic you'll see your query makes no sense; for some rows a table needs to be joined, for other records a different table, this doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you ☺ You are right this will not work when getting rows from other tables and I need to get them as wel. I solved this problem using `UNION` approach!