# SQL Select string not working

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I've already posted this but I want to explain it better. I have a website in which students insert their 4 courses and 4 comments for each course, these are the SQL table columns:
Course1, Course2, Course 3, Course 4, Comment1, Comment2, Comment 3, Comment 4.

I have a search in which any student inputs, for instance, geography (which may be saved in any of the four course columns), and I want my SQL query to return all the comments for geography. For example, if a student saved Geography in position Course2, I want my SQL query to select comment2 where course2 = geography. He may have saved it in course1, so it has to be flexible, but only select the course chosen by the student. This is my current SQL query:

```
$SQL = "SELECT (Comment1 FROM Students WHERE Course1 = 'geography'), (Comment2 FROM Students WHERE Course2 = 'geography'), (Comment3 FROM Students WHERE Course3 = 'geography'),  (Comment4 FROM Students WHERE Course4 = 'geography')";
```

Currently, this SQL query isn't working.
I know the structure may seem odd, but logically, as you may understand, this makes sense, though it's probably not the right way to code it. I then print all the geography comments like this:

```
$null = '';
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  echo "<ol>";  
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($row["Class"]!=$null) {  
  if($null!='') {  
  echo "</ol><ol type='1'>";   
  } 
 }

 echo "<li><p>" . " " . $row["Comment1"]. " " . $row["Comment2"]." " .    $row["Comment3"] . " " . $row["Comment4"] . "</li></p>";
$i = $i +1;
}

echo "</ol>";
```

Comment: you have to check your condition for $value1 in order to fetch data corresponding to it.
check for which course and then fetch its comments

Comment: The subqueries need to have the same structure as any other select query. i.e. (SELECT Comment1 FROM...

Comment: That query looks ....odd. Can you please [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33968228/edit) the table definition (as shown by `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`)  and some sample data?

Comment: Your `select` looks invalid and open to SQL injections. Have you tried outputting the errors when executing and/or executing the query directly on your DB?

Comment: If I say, "Separate the comments columns out into a separate table," it sounds facile, but it really would save you from some horrendous headaches down the road.

Comment: Off topic, but I notice that you're using PHP's `mysql_query()`, `mysql_num_rows()`, etc functions. Please be aware that the `mysql_xxx` functions are obsolete; in fact, they're being removed entirely from the new version of PHP coming out soon, so you really should be considering switching your code to use one of the more modern database APIs in PHP. Either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries would be fine.

Comment: To make it easier to give a correct answer, you should probably show us what the database table structure looks like as well as the PHP code.

Comment: When I run that, it says: Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available. Documentation

Comment: I know, but I get that message. Anyway, you can see the table structure here:
http://s27.postimg.org/6cdpitjoj/table.jpg

Comment: I know we're nagging you, but please, please, no _picture_ of the structure. Makes it damn hard to fiddle with it ;-) afaik phpmyadmin can export the table without data; the result should be more or less the same as that of show create table. Anyway, how much code is "around" that table (i.e. code depending on that table structure)? Would it be ok to almost totally revamp that and make it more "standard" relational database-ish?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not an option. Anyway, I tried exporting it but it keeps the data inside it.

Comment: "I'm sorry, that's not an option." - the revamp thingy? Too bad, the table structure ...has some limitations. But ok, in real life the database is what it is most of the times ;-)

Comment: @Drew should I delete the answer? It's 6 am here, no sleep and I really can't tell if the answer I posted is good or not. I just saw that OP is struggling on this one.

Comment: No @KostasMitsarakis. Not at all. It answers what he is asking. Part of our self-imposed responsibility is to try to ferret out what is going on. Constructive words even if they rattle a bit. That comment was not meant to rip into you at all

Comment: I second that in general - but there will be probably also code changes; and when you change that more or less ad hoc, _you_ own that code, too. That's often _not_ what you want for various reasons ;-)

Comment: You're getting too complicated for a guy who started learning programming from scratch just two months ago guys. I'm gonna read properly through your answers, try and make them work for me, then come back to you. But thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong: 
Try this

```
SELECT Comment1, Comment2, Comment3, Comment4 
FROM Students 
WHERE Course1 = '$value1' AND Course2 = '$value1' 
AND Course3 = '$value1' AND Course4 = '$value1'
```

OR

```
SELECT Comment1, Comment2, Comment3, Comment4 
FROM Students 
WHERE Course1 = '$value1' OR Course2 = '$value1' 
OR Course3 = '$value1' OR Course4 = '$value1'
```

Based on your requirement use AND or OR while checking course

Comment: No, that's not it. With the AND, it selects comments when all 4 courses are equal to the one course the user inserted at the same time, which will never happen, everyone has different courses.

With the latter example, it will still select all courses when one course OR another course in the database is equal to the searched one.

Every row has 4 different courses and 4 corresponding comments. Say that a user looks for "History". I want to select comment1 where course 1 = History, or comment 2 where course2 = History, etc. This is because users may input same courses but in different position!

Comment: Ohk... then please try the if statements in mysql.. just check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I have understood what you want but you can try this (untested):

```
SELECT Student_ID, 
    CASE
        WHEN Course1 = 'geography' THEN Comment1
        ELSE NULL
    END AS comment1_result,
    CASE
        WHEN Course2 = 'geography' THEN Comment2
        ELSE NULL
    END AS comment2_result,
    CASE
        WHEN Course3 = 'geography' THEN Comment3
        ELSE NULL
    END AS comment3_result,
    CASE
        WHEN Course4 = 'geography' THEN Comment4
        ELSE NULL
    END AS comment4_result
FROM Students
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that table structure really(sic) can't be changed (anymore) I'd go with a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) here

```
    ( SELECT Comment1 as comment FROM soFoo WHERE Course1='geography' )
UNION ALL
    ( SELECT Comment2 as comment FROM soFoo WHERE Course2='geography' )
UNION ALL
    ( SELECT Comment3 as comment FROM soFoo WHERE Course3='geography' )
UNION ALL
    ( SELECT Comment4 as comment FROM soFoo WHERE Course4='geography' )
```

It gives MySQL at least a fighting chance to use indices to find the matching records.