# SQL query - Isn't selecting correct columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, select

I've already posted this but I want to explain it better. I have a website in which students insert their 4 courses and 4 comments for each course, these are the SQL table columns:
Course1, Course2, Course 3, Course 4, Comment1, Comment2, Comment 3, Comment 4.

I have a search in which any student inputs, for instance, geography (which may be saved in any of the four course columns), and I want my SQL query to return all the comments for geography. For example, if a student saved Geography in position Course2, I want my SQL query to select comment2 where course2 = geography. He may have saved it in course1, so it has to be flexible, but only select the course chosen by the student. This is my current SQL query:

```
$SQL = "SELECT (Comment1 FROM Students WHERE Course1 = 'geography'), (Comment2 FROM Students WHERE Course2 = 'geography'), (Comment3 FROM Students WHERE Course3 = 'geography'),  (Comment4 FROM Students WHERE Course4 = 'geography')";
```

Currently, this SQL query isn't working.
I know the structure may seem odd, but logically, as you may understand, this makes sense, though it's probably not the right way to code it. I then print all the geography comments like this:

```
$null = '';
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  echo "<ol>";  
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($row["Class"]!=$null) {  
  if($null!='') {  
  echo "</ol><ol type='1'>";   
  } 
 }

 echo "<li><p>" . " " . $row["Comment1"]. " " . $row["Comment2"]." " .    $row["Comment3"] . " " . $row["Comment4"] . "</li></p>";
$i = $i +1;
}

echo "</ol>";
```

Comment: I took the liberty of copy&pasting this question's text over to the "original". But you still should [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33968228/edit) the definition of your database tables to the question text.

Comment: Yeah good job, now nobody will answer me ...

Comment: I e.g. have it bookmarked, only waiting for the table definition. Your explainition this time is better. I guess it will result in restructering your table and adjusting the query accordingly. There's a "mark as duplicate" option for a reason.

Comment: Ok, thank you. What do you mean exactly by table definition?

Comment: how about if you delete this question and we move to your other question from yesterday ?

Comment: The structure of the table(s) involved. It seems you currently have only one table, `Students` -> [`SHOW CREATE TABLE Students`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html). In case you do not have a frontend for fiddling with your MySQL server, I suggest [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) (windows only though....)

Comment: because there is no point being here anymore

Comment: yes, please, let's continue with the ["original" question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968228/sql-select-string-not-working)