# MySQL move one of the returned results the bottom

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with a MySQL query any help would be good.

Basically the project I'm doing is to record and display golf scores. I have a query that gets all the players morning score and afternoon score adds them together and displays lowest score at the top.

I have an extra field for priority which checks if two plays are on the same score and I can assign a number to display them above the other. All this works fine, the issue I have is if a player only plays the morning or afternoon they are displayed at the top because they have the lowest score. I need to add something to check if they have played both morning and afternoon if not then they go to the bottom of the list. Hope that make sense.

**My database fields are**

```
player_id, 
player_name, 
player_morning_score, 
player_afternoon_score,
player_priority,
player_no_return
```

I was hoping to put a 1 in the player_no_return and then my query would check for this and move them to the bottom of my results. But I'm not sure how to go about it.

**Here's my query for currently displaying them.**

```
SELECT player_id, player_name, (player_morning_score + player_afternoon_score) AS total
FROM players
ORDER BY 'total,player_priority', 'ASC','player_afternoon_score', 'DESC'
```

At the minute my results look like this

```
Craig    10 

Steve    15

Julie    21

Alex     21

Bob      25
```

Craig has only played the morning so would need moving to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting by strings, which means you are not sorting , use back ticks for columns/aliasing : ` and not single quote mark that represent a string. Although you don't even need them(they are used for more then 1 word alias , or reserved words) :

```
SELECT player_id, player_name,
       player_morning_score + player_afternoon_score AS total
FROM players 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN player_afternoon_score > 0 AND player_morning_score > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
          `total`,player_priority,player_afternoon_score DESC
```

`ORDER BY` default is `ASC` , so you don't have to write it down, only when you want `DESC`.

I added you requirment (if he didn't play both, he will be on the bottom of the list) using `CASE EXPRESSION` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Check IF statement in SELECT. ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

You can select column if player played in the morning or not placing 1 or 0 value. Then order by this field and total