# how to diplay values with * in sql table

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a table called "Vaccine" as follows

```
vaccine_name |   date  | expired
-------------------------
coldact      | 12-12-12 | N
cough        | 11-11-11 | Y
asparin      | 10-10-10 | Y
```

I want a select clause which displays '*' on Expired dates

```
vaccine_name |   date  | 
-------------------------
coldact      | 12-12-12*
cough        | 11-11-11 
asparin      | 10-10-10
```

something like :

```
Select vaccine_name,date case when
expired = 'N' then '*'
else date
from Vaccine
where date < 09-09-09;
```

I want a * next to date value where expired = 'N' in SQL.

Comment: Please view similar question already answered on Stack Overflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values

Comment: Use CONCAT to merge two strings. CONCAT (date, "\*"). To get "12-12-12*".

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date to a string.  I would recommend YYYY-MM-DD format (but you can choose whatever you want).

In Oracle:

```
Select vaccine_name,
       (to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ||
        (case when expired = 'N' then '*'
              else ''
         end
        )
       )
from Vaccine;
```

I removed the `where` clause because it doesn't seem to fit your desired results.