# SQL ORDER BY - Choose order by value between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table which looks like the following:

```
 id     id2     name
--------------------
 4      NULL     A
 3       2       B
 5      NULL     C
 1       6       D
```

Now I want to ORDER BY id DESC (which is not the problem)

But: 
WHEN id2 IST NOT NULL 
the **id2** value should be used in ORDER BY 
instead of the **id** value

Sounds simple but I just dont get it working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
order by coalesce(id2, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from table_name order by id,id2`.

Comment: hey, id should be ignored when id2 is not null - then order by