# How to create temporary sequence in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know it even possible to create temporary sequence in MYSQL sql query. If it is possible please advise how it is done for example

I have a column name called

Phase and data below

- Phase A
- Phase C
- Phase B
- Phase D

I want to query out and create a sequence number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 base on phase a, b, c, d...so the query output will become

```
Seq     Phase
---------------
1       Phase A
2       Phase B
3       Phase C
4       Phase D
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that you need a temporary auto_increment column?

Comment: I want to make a query and create a temporary sequence column base on the order by a column name alphabetical

Comment: So column Phase contains A,C,B,D. But you want output to be 1,3,2,4 instead?

Comment: If there are relatively small amount of phase values, you could use the `IF` function or `CASE` statement. If larger amount, I'd use a lookup table that you would join to. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values among others.

Comment: That dupe target shown on the Close has a nice answer from `OMG Ponies` .

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether I am answering your question properly. As I understood, you want to generate a sequence on the fly for your results set. Could help more if this is not exactly what you require.

```
SELECT @seq:=@seq+1 id, column_1, column_2 FROM your_table, (SELECT @seq:=0) a;
```

Comment: No, that's not what he wants. Just to replace alpha values with numeric ones. There are many examples already here of that.

Comment: @picmate thats what i want i think topshot misunderstood my intention...but using your query there is an error says "Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 unrecognized token: ":")

Comment: Happy to help. Are you running it from a script of some kind? If so, could you first try running it in mysql server itself? The query works perfectly for me.

Comment: @picmate i will try it tomorrow when i got back to work and see how it goes

Comment: @rookie_coder so your "exactly" comment wasn't accurate? Perhaps you failed to mention that Phase doesn't have limited values - that it in itself is a unique sequence?

Comment: @picmate brilliant that query exactly answered my question now i have sequence column on the fly perfect thanks