# Change MySql output based on different column values

Tags: mysql

I am using the query below which gives me all reports and its Excel Format ID 
for example 1=Excel 2007, 2=XLSX, 3=CSV

```
SELECT Reportname AS 'ReportName', Excelformatid AS 'Excel Format' FROM reports;
```

Is it possible to get the actual format instead of the ID, in the output?

I went through the below link, but it tells me how I can change the output considering only a specific column value, and not all.

['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Comment: A conditional is far too complicated. Simply create a table holding the formats as reference and turn the select statement into a join with that table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT
    Reportname AS 'ReportName',
    CASE
        WHEN Excelformatid = 1 THEN 'Excel 2007'
        WHEN Excelformatid = 2 THEN 'XLSX'
        WHEN Excelformatid = 3 THEN 'CSV'
    END CASE AS 'Excel Format'
FROM
    reports
```

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) for the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to make a lookup table and do a join, but if you don't have that available a [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) will do the trick.

```
SELECT 
    Reportname AS 'ReportName', 
    CASE Excelformatid
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Excel 2007'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'XLSX'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'CSV'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS 'Excel Format' 
FROM reports;
```

It would be easy to implement a lookup table (let's call it 'formats') with data like this:

```
+---------------+------------+
| Excelformatid | name       |
+---------------+------------+
| 1             | Excel 2007 |
| 2             | XLSX       |
| 3             | CSV        |
+---------------+------------+
```

Then you can use a join like so:

```
SELECT Reportname, formats.name
FROM reports
LEFT JOIN formats USING(Excelformatid)
```

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a look up table but your suggestion of using CASE worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
    Reportname AS 'ReportName',
CASE
    WHEN Excelformatid = '1' THEN 'Excel 2007'
    WHEN Excelformatid = '2' THEN 'XLSX'
    WHEN Excelformatid = '3' THEN 'CSV'
END AS 'Formate Not Available'
FROM
    reports
```

Also You can make masterformat table and join with reports which give you dynamic result

1. Create Table
2. Insert Data
3. Join With reports table