# How to Show Top Value filed as top in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to show the college name and num of applications comes to each college and show most application received college as first position in MySQL query?

This is sample table, `clg` is college name and `application_name` column must be `count()` and highest value field must be show on top

[image]

My results must be like this....

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT `clg`,count(`clg`) AS clg 
FROM demo 
GROUP BY `clg` 
ORDER BY clg DESC
```

Comment: I am very surprised that this works.  There are two columns named `clg` in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this because the columns in a `select` should be unique, particularly when they are referenced in the `order by` clause.  The query should look more like:

```
SELECT s.clg, count(*) as cnt 
FROM sample s 
GROUP BY s.clg
ORDER BY cnt DESC ;
```