# Get all results from MySQL query when no parameter has been sent

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js

I am working on a NodeJS/MySQL application.

There is a dropdown (**salesperson**) and each option has a value which is being sent as a criteria into a MySQL query for rows of the same table.

I need to have an "All" option (for ***salesperson***) which will not abstract results based on this selection and it will function like ignoring the specific criteria in the MySQL query so or alternatively work as a wildcard for it which makes more sense.

However I can't figure out how to pass or not to pass at all this criteria for when I have the "All salespersons" selected (no value).

**Function which passes the form's selected options as values into MySQL query**

```
var field = req.body.mode;
var start_date = req.body.start_date;
var end_date = req.body.end_date;
var operator = req.body.operator;
var paid_operator = req.body.paid_operator;
var user_id = user.id;
var salesperson = req.body.salesperson;

db.select_between_dates_office( table, field, start_date, end_date, user_id, 
salesperson, function(data) { // do something
});
```

**MySQL query**

```
this.select_between_dates_office = function( table, field, start_date, end_date, user_id, 
salesperson, callback ){

var query_string = "select * from "+ table +" where "+ field +" between '"+ start_date +"' 
and '"+ end_date + "' and user_id='" + user_id +"' and salesperson='" + salesperson + "'"; 

connection.query( query_string, function(err,rows){
    callback (rows);
     })
}
```

Comment: You can create query with ``case`` instruction. Like in [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5951174/6557808).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when no salesperson is selected, you should have an if condition which doesn't include the `salesperson` where clause like:

```
if(salesperson !== '') {
    var query_string = "select * from "+ table +" where "+ field +" between '"+ start_date +"' 
and '"+ end_date + "' and user_id='" + user_id +"' and salesperson='" + salesperson + "'"; 
} else {
    var query_string = "select * from "+ table +" where "+ field +" between '"+ start_date +"' 
and '"+ end_date + "' and user_id='" + user_id + "'"; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, I was making it hard by locking my mind into the medium function instead of the conditional statement in the db clause as you suggested which was much easier. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Imho what you were requesting should be standard DB behaviour. Makes more sense to do a simple check on the parameter and not execute if you do not want to return all, than to duplicate code. Sadly enough this seems to be the only way.