# how to set where condition under if result

Tags: mysql

I have four different where condition.

And I get 2 values(A,B) from outside.

If both A and B are null

I want to select rows under first where condition.

If A is null and B is not, the second where condition.

If A is not null and B is null, the third.

If Both A and B are not null, the fourth.

Let me show it to you briefly.

```
select * from mytable 
if(A ==null and B == null)
   first where condition
if(A == null and B != null)
   second where condition

  ......
```

How can I do this with SQL

Comment: you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values ) I think you can find the answer there!

Comment: `I have four different where clauses.` ... there is only one `WHERE` clause in a SQL query.  It is not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: I suggest: substitute the word "condition" where you see "clause" in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use case clause, and i think it will be easier for you.
This is the example for your problem, i hope this code can help you.

`SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE name = 
CASE WHEN A IS NULL AND B IS NULL THEN 'john'
     WHEN A IS NULL AND B IS NOT NULL THEN 'doe'
     ...
END;`

Answer (score 0):

Four different sets of conditions you want to meet:

1. If both A and B are null , and...
2. If A is null and B is not , and ...
3. If A is not null and B is null , and ...
4. If Both A and B are not null , and ...

These could be expressed like this:

```
WHERE (A IS NULL     AND B IS NULL     AND NAME = 'Fred')
   OR (A IS NULL     AND B IS NOT NULL AND NAME = 'Barney')
   OR (A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NULL     AND NAME = 'Wilma')
   OR (A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL AND NAME = 'Betty')
```