# Compare variables then set a variable (IF sql)

Tags: mysql, sql

Tryng and failing to discover the correct syntax for an IF or IIF within a SQL SELECT (MySQL)

Compare 2 variables and if different then set another variable to a value

```
IF(assetID <> previousAssetID) set @ts = vardtmin
```

Do I need another specifier that sts something to 1 if the statement resolves true?

The full SELECT is -

```
SELECT 
assetID, 
IF(assetdID <> previousAssetID) set @ts=vardtmin, 
nodeid, 
@changed := IF(nodeid <> previousLocationID, @changed + 1, @changed) AS changed, 
IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, previousTs, ts), 0) AS secDiff
```

Regards
Active

Comment: Is this code snippet in the context of a stored proc, query, trigger, or something else?

Comment: Show us a complete SELECT query!

Comment: Look at this blog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values

Comment: Full SELECT added (see original post), within a stored procedure.

Comment: Where are you going to use `@ts` variable?

Comment: set and used in multiple other locations (complex, multiple nested select statement), those parts are working. There is just something wrong with the syntax in the IF(assetID statement

Comment: This code is a mess, can you please describe what exactly you want to do?

Comment: If the values in assetID and previousAssetID are different then set the variable @ts to the value in the variable vardtmin (which is a datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know MYSQL but SQL syntax will be like below :-

```
SELECT 
assetID, 
@ts = case when assetdID <> previousAssetID then vardtmin else 111 end , 
nodeid, 
@changed = case when  nodeid <> previousLocationID @changed + 1 else  @changed AS changed, 
case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, previousTs, ts), 0) isnull then .. else .. end  AS secDiff
```

Comment: Thanks chanchal, please explain what the 111 does (If assetID and previousAssetID are the same then @ts must not be changed)

Comment: what does that mean is some other value if you want to update , but syntax should be like this.