# Is it possible to use if else condition true fetch from one table else another table?

Tags: java, mysql

```
select * from table1 t1 if( t1.purchase =='1')
    select t2.price from table2 t2 where t2.id=t1.id
else 
    select t3.price from table3 t3 where t3.id=t1.id
end if as amt
```

I tried this but its not working how to use if condition in SQL and fetch the details from MySQL database please give hints guys.

iam asking if condtion true get from table 2 else table 3 its not the same question

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Comment: this one is showing error i tried in php myadmin

Comment: This is horrible database schema design.

Comment: Hello MatMat try to understand the question first that is different ,this is different ,how come its duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing your tables, data and expected output. 
Questions should include these to get good answers. 
But this query might do the trick.

```
SELECT
   * 
 , IF(t1.purchase = '1', t2.price, t3.price) as amt
FROM 
 table1 t1

INNER JOIN 
 table2 t2
ON 
 t1.id = t2.id 

INNER JOIN 
 table3 t3 
ON
 t1.id = t3.id
```

Or with missing values in table2 or table3 use a LEFT JOIN (Editted because off Turo's comment)

```
SELECT
   * 
 , IF(t1.purchase = '1', t2.price, t3.price) as amt
FROM 
 table1 t1

LEFT JOIN 
 table2 t2
ON 
 t1.id = t2.id 

LEFT JOIN 
 table3 t3 
ON
 t1.id = t3.i
```

Comment: Since it's not sure that there has always to be a value in both table2 and table3 i would propose a left outer join

Comment: dude its execute but no value is getting t2.price and t3.price how it works

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 "dude its execute but no value is getting"... Not knowing your tables, data and expected output.
Questions should include these to get good answers...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to do this from your SQL code, I would handle the switch between queries in your Java code.  Something like this:

```
String query1 = "select t2.price from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id";
String query2 = "select t3.price from table3 t3 where t3.id = t1.id";
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
if (t1.purchase == '1') {
    rs = statement.executeQuery(query1);
}
else {
    rs = statement.executeQuery(query2);
}
if (rs.next()) {
    double price = rs.getDouble("price");
}
```

In response to the downvotes, yes the OP may not have an optimal database design.  But it is possible that this situation could legitimately happen in real life.