# Count first letter of titles and print A to Z

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count the first letter of the titles so that I can have a list of A to Z.
The problem is I can`t display the letters that have 0 count.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(UCASE(title), 1, 1) as letter, count(id) as total 
FROM `a-z` 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1)
```

this query gives me this result:

[image]

How can I print all the letters from A to Z and display 0 for the count if there is no title starting with that letter such as?

```
A 1
B 0
C 0
...
Z 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Comment: You want an `IF` statement in your SQL, so that ***if*** count > 0 output count else output 0.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2):

You need a list of all the letters you care about:

```
SELECT l.letter, count(az.id) as total 
FROM (SELECT 'a' as letter UNION ALL
      SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
      . . .
      SELECT 'z'
     ) letters LEFT JOIN
     `a-z` az
     ON l.letter = LEFT(az.title, 1)
GROUP BY l.letter;
```

Comment: To generate letters, you can use stored procedures.