# How to integrate while loop into SQL query? (Repeating last result in the column)

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to build a query using a while loop to obtain the final Result column.

Let say I already have a query (My_query) where I am extracting the following information.

[image: Output sample]

My_query is giving me already all the information below without the **Result** column. My plan was to include a while loop that allows me to identify the correct status for each Period and ID. The logic I was trying to use was the following:

```
Declare i int = 0
Declare j int = 0
Declare buffer int = 0

With My_query as (My query code is here)

Select *,
       Result = 

 while (i <= 12) --This will be the number of rows coming from My_query.
    Begin
    set buffer = 0 -- Resetting the status variable for the next ID
        while (j <= 6) -- This will be the number of periods for every ID. Max(Block)
        Begin
            If (Block = 1 and Status_History IS NULL) -- Block = 1 always will be the higher period consulted in My_query.
                Set Result = Current_Status
                Set buffer = Result
            If (Block = 1 and Status_History IS NOT NULL)
                Set Result = Status_History
                Set buffer = Result
            If (Block <> 1 and Status_History IS NULL)
                Set Result = buffer
            If (Block <> 1 and Status_History IS NOT NULL)
                Set Result = Status_History
                Set buffer = Result
        Set j = j+1
        END
    Set i = i+1
    END
From My_query
```

**Solution:**
The best way I found to solve this problem was creating an index (besides the "Block" one) that allows me to identify specific changes by group. The index assign 0 to NULL values and every time a value different than NULL is found it SUM 1 to the index. When the ID change, the index reset. This solution is way lighter on resources consumption.

**Index**

```
SUM(CASE 
WHEN(Status_History) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Period DESC) AS IND
```

**Solution**

```
WITH DAT AS (My_query)

SELECT *,
CASE WHEN IND = 0 THEN DAT.Current_Status ELSE MAX(DAT.Status_History) OVER ( PARTITION BY DAT.ID, DAT.IND ORDER BY DAT.Period DESC) END AS Result
FROM DAT
ORDER BY ID, Period DESC
```

```
 ID Period  Current_Status  Status_History  IND Block   Result
1012    201903  32  NULL    0   1   32
1012    201902  32  NULL    0   2   32
1012    201901  32  16  1   3   16
1012    201812  32  NULL    1   4   16
1012    201811  32  NULL    1   5   16
1012    201810  32  10  2   6   10
1012    201809  32  NULL    2   7   10
5124    201903  25  NULL    0   1   25
5124    201902  25  23  2   2   23
5124    201901  25  29  3   3   29
5124    201812  25  NULL    4   4   29
5124    201811  25  NULL    5   5   29
5124    201810  25  NULL    6   6   29
5124    201809  25  NULL    7   7   29
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually need a loop to iterate through the result set as functions in the SELECT statement are executed on each result record.

You can use Control Flow Functions as described in the [MySQL documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) to handle the relevant data in your result. There are some examples of this in this stackoverflow question ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values#5951204) or you can also use a combination of the different Data combination statements in MySQL

I did have success getting the expected output based on the image you provided by using a combination of `UNION`, `JOIN` and subqueries.

### Code

```
  SELECT *, mqa.Current_Status as Result 
  FROM MyQuery mqa
  WHERE 
    mqa.Block = 1 
    AND mqa.Status_History IS NULL
  UNION
  SELECT mqb.*, mqb.Status_History as Result 
  FROM MyQuery mqb
  WHERE 
    Status_History IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT mqc.ID,
       mqc.Period,
       mqc.Current_Status,
       mqc.Status_History,
       mqc.Block,
       (SELECT TOP 1 mqd.Status_History FROM MyQuery mqd
                    WHERE mqd.ID = mqc.ID
                        AND mqd.Block < mqc.Block
                        AND mqd.Status_History IS NOT NULL
                     ORDER BY Block DESC)
        FROM MyQuery mqc
                  WHERE 
                    mqc.Status_History IS NULL
                    AND mqc.Block <> 1
```

### Results

```
|     ID | Period | Current_Status | Status_History | Block | Result |
|--------|--------|----------------|----------------|-------|--------|
| 012014 | 201710 |              5 |         (null) |     6 |      7 |
| 012014 | 201711 |              5 |              7 |     5 |      7 |
| 012014 | 201712 |              5 |         (null) |     4 |      3 |
| 012014 | 201810 |              5 |         (null) |     3 |      3 |
| 012014 | 201811 |              5 |              3 |     2 |      3 |
| 012014 | 201812 |              5 |         (null) |     1 |      5 |
| 012015 | 201710 |              2 |         (null) |     6 |     10 |
| 012015 | 201711 |              2 |         (null) |     5 |     10 |
| 012015 | 201712 |              2 |         (null) |     4 |     10 |
| 012015 | 201810 |              2 |         (null) |     3 |     10 |
| 012015 | 201811 |              2 |         (null) |     2 |     10 |
| 012015 | 201812 |              2 |             10 |     1 |     10 |
```

You can play with the code above in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/036e7/42)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really like the logic you're using here and I think it can be less time consuming than using a while loop. I have to things to point out:

**Fisrt:** I'm getting the following error:
_Column 'MyQuery.Current_Status' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause_

Comment: **Second:** Could you explain me in more detail what is logic in this point:

`SELECT a.*,MAX(b.Status_History) as Result 
  FROM MyQuery a
  JOIN MyQuery b
    ON b.ID = a.ID
    AND b.Block < a.Block
    AND b.Status_History IS NOT NULL
  WHERE 
    a.Status_History IS NULL
    AND a.Block <> 1
  GROUP BY a.ID, a.Period)`

Comment: BTW, I saw you were using MySQL 5.6 on the SQL Fiddle platform. I changed to SQL Server and now the error is being shown in the example as well.

Comment: **Update:** I was able to get results including all the columns in the _group by_ clause. The issue now is, because the code is using `MAX(b.Status_History)` cases where the status starts with a larger number the result is miss classify until it finds a larger value or the ID change.

Comment: The whole point of my answer was for you to take a look at Subqueries, `JOIN`, and `UNION` statements and not use loops because it is very unnecessary. I updated the query for you, the updated query will take into account Status_History which start out with greater numbers than the ones in the later blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are falling back on the first non-null value of the previous record when a condition is not met. In theory this could be a coalesce result of the previous values and the current values looking for the first non-null in the desired order.

```
With My_query as (My query code is here)

SELECT i,Block,
    Result = 
        CASE WHEN (Block=1) THEN 
            COALESCE(Status_History,Current_History) 
        ELSE 
            COALESCE(Status_History, LAG(Status_History) OVER (PARTITION BY Block ORDER BY i),LAG(Current_Status) OVER (PARTITION BY Block ORDER BY i)
        END
FROM
    My_Query
```