# Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION tickets.IIF does not exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I try to collect general statistics on the depth of correspondence: average, maximum and minimum number of messages of each type per one request. Have 2 tables:

First:
ticketId,ticketQueueId,ticketCreatedDate

Second:
articleId,articleCreatedDt,articleType (can be IN or OUT - support responses), ticketId

I reasoned like this:

```
SELECT 
AVG(qty_IN) avg_art_IN,
MAX(qty_IN) max_art_IN,
MIN(qty_IN) min_art_IN,
AVG(qty_OUT) avg_art_OUT,
MAX(qty_OUT) max_art_OUT,
MIN(qty_OUT) min_art_OUT
FROM 
(SELECT
ticketId, 
SUM(IIF(articleType='IN',1,0)) qty_IN,
SUM(IIF(articleType='OUT',1,0)) qty_OUT
FROM tickets.articles
GROUP BY ticketId
) AS t
```

Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION tickets.IIF does not exist

Comment: That's true it doesn't..and I'm puzzled why you would try to use this construct in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use If instead

```
SUM(IF(articleType='IN',1,0)) qty_IN
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use if function  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if

or case

```
SUM(case when articleType='IN' then 1 else 0 end) qty_IN,
```