# How to convert tinyint back to boolean when reading from SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
`mysql> select * from movies;
+----------+-------+---------+
| movie_id | title | watched |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 | bo    |       0 |
|        2 | NEW   |       0 |
|        3 | NEW 2 |       0 |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIES (
  movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  watched BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id)
);
```

`
I am having to store the "watched" field as a tiny int instead of typical boolean, I am trying to find a way of converting it back to boolean when reading from table, so I dont have to loop through all responses and convert manually.

ie. `{movie_id: 1, title: 'bo', watched: 0} ---> {movie_id: 1, title: 'bo', watched: false}`

I have tried select cast but am unfamiliar with the syntax

Comment: You have to read the records into a domain object at some point though - so why not just cast the values then rather than in the db layer?

Comment: "I am having to store the "watched" field as a tiny int instead of typical boolean" => When doing `SHOW CREATE TABLE movies`, on the table where you have this field defined as BOOLEAN, you will notice the type of the field `watched` to be a `tinyint(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL saves Boolean as 0 and 1 as it handles all Boolean that way.

It is very practical, then you can add true or false from a comparison in a `SUM` without `CASE WHEN` or a `FILTER`

You need still to make a condition to give bak True or False, but they only text of course

```
SELECT
  movie_id , title , 
 CASE WHEN watched = 0 THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to ['IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values)

Borrowing from the answer there,

```
SELECT movie_id, IF (watched > 0, true, false) as bwatched, ...
```

Note that this assumes your schema still includes "NOT NULL" for watched.  Without that (or some extra code) NULL would become false.

The way "IF()" works is `IF(expression , value / expression  if true, v /e if false)`